# Fixing WordPress Header

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-theming

I was provided this bit of code to add to my functions.php file by the support team of the company from whom I bought the theme.

I wanted my logo and site name side by side and they gave me this code:

```
function igthemes_site_logo() { 
$custom_logo_id = get_theme_mod( 'custom_logo' );
$image = wp_get_attachment_image_src( $custom_logo_id , 'full' );
$url = home_url( '/' );
echo '<a href="' . esc_url( $url ) .'">'; 
echo "<img class='logo' src= " . $image[0] . " style='float:left; padding:15px;'>";
echo '<div style="float:left; padding:15px 0;">' . get_bloginfo( 'title' ) . '</div>';
echo '</a>';
}
```

However, that made it look like this.[Two logos and titles](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gD95r.jpg)

What do I change to just show one logo and one title?

Comment: it seems like that php function (`igthemes_site_logo()`) is called twice. That would be in the PHP code, not in the code you posted which only contains the function itself.

Comment: Hey Johannes, thank you so much. I forgot to add one more line that was in the file: add_action( 'igthemes_site_branding', 'igthemes_site_logo', 5 );

Is this what you're talking about?

Comment: yes, probably...

Comment: Hey Johannes, I edited it by removing the igthemes_site_logo and it worked brilliantly. Thanks! However, I honestly just added the site logo by creating a custom banner on InDesign. That worked much better because it was way more elegant.

Thank you so much!

Comment: you are welcome! BTW, I added my comment as an answer now...

Comment: Yes, thanks. I wondered if I could do it. Apparently, StackOverflow does not even consider my upvote worthy enough to be displayed.

Comment: You "marked the answer as the correct answer", which isn't the same as an upvote - but also a way of appreciation. For new users there is a minimum time only *after* which they can vote, AFAIR (but I'm not sure anymore)

Comment: Hey Johannes, I have a follow up question I need your help with. Is it possible to chat somewhere?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it seems like that php function (igthemes_site_logo()) is called twice. That would be in the PHP code, not in the code you posted which only contains the function itself.